# .NET HttpClient/RestSharp with X509 Certificate throws "The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception." after NET 5 upgrade

Tags: c#, .net, ssl, x509certificate, .net-5

I am currently upgrading code from .NET 4.7.2 to .NET 5. When the code below is ran under NET 4.7.2 it successfully connects to webserver, under NET 5 it throws this exception:

```
Exception: "The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception."
 -> InnerException: "Authentication failed, see inner exception."
   -> InnerException: "An unknown error occurred while processing"
```

Why would I get different behaviour between .NET 4.7.2 to .NET 5?

You get the same exception if you don't provide a cert. I have tried loading the cert from both a .pfx file and the local machine's X509Store. I also had other developers in at company try and they got the same result.

The code is being ran on Windows 10, using VS 2019 but the same issue occurs behaviour occurs when deployed to a Windows IIS server.

*Please help because I'm out of ideas*

```
using RestSharp;
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;

namespace SwipeTestNet5
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                // certificate store fetching
                var store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);

                store.Open(OpenFlags.OpenExistingOnly | OpenFlags.ReadOnly);

                // getting the certificate from the store based on the app setting certificateName
                // !! obviously this url is not the real one
                var certificateName = "test-cert-name";
                // the following line will error if there are certificates with the same friendly name... you shouldn't have let this happen
                var cert = store.Certificates.Cast<X509Certificate2>().SingleOrDefault(c => c.FriendlyName == certificateName);

                if (cert == null)
                    throw new Exception("Could not find certificate with name: " + certificateName);

                // Handle any certificate errors on the certificate from the server.
                ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

                // !! obviously this url is not the real one
                var url = "https://test.com.au/api";
                var client = new RestClient(url);
                var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);

                client.ClientCertificates = new X509CertificateCollection(new[] { cert });

                // Handle any certificate errors on the certificate from the server.
                // !! When ran under .NET 4.7.2 this callback is triggred, under .NET 5 it never reaches
                client.RemoteCertificateValidationCallback = (sender, certificate, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;

                // !! obviously this url is not the real parameters
                var parameters = new
                {
                    param1 = "a",
                    param2 = "b",
                    param3 = "c"
                };

                request.AddObject(parameters);

                var response = client.Execute(request);

                // !! Under NET 4.7.2 response.ErrorException is null and continues
                // !! Under NET 5 the response.ErrorException is populated with this:
                //      ErrorException: "The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception."
                //          -> InnerException: "Authentication failed, see inner exception."
                //              -> InnerException: "An unknown error occurred while processing the certificate."
                if (response.ErrorException != null)
                    throw response.ErrorException;

                // !! NET 4.7.2 gets to here without issue
                if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
                {
                    Exception ex = new Exception($"Error calling {client}");

                    ex.Data.Add("xml", response.Content);
                    ex.Data.Add("status code", response.StatusCode);
                    ex.Data.Add("param1", parameters.param1);
                    ex.Data.Add("param2", parameters.param2);
                    ex.Data.Add("param3", parameters.param3);

                    throw ex;
                }

                Console.WriteLine("Success");
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please retry with the standard `HttpClient` and see if you have the same issue.

Comment: Also, in .NET 5, there should be no need to mess around with `ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol` - .NET supports, and will automatically use, the appropriate SSL/TLS protocol.

Comment: @IanKemp I get the same behaviour with HttpClient

Answer (score 2):

The problem is here:

```
var store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);
```

The App Pool identity does not have Administrator permission by default, but that permission is required to read keys from the Local Machine store. Either explicitly grant read permissions to the key stored in Local Machine, or install the certificate in the App Pool identity's personal store (Current User context).

In order to grant the App Pool identity read permissions for Local Machine, navigate to the certificate, right-click and select All Tasks -> Manage Private Keys menu item:
[image]

Comment: The certificate is not null because you can read public part of certificate, but not private key.

Comment: I will give this a shot but I get the same behaviour when I load the cert from a file directly.

Comment: Sorry this did not work. I have granted access to the cert to current user and all users, still get the same result.

Answer (score -1):

Change this

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

with this

```
   ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls;
or
    ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3;
```

or allow ignoring the error

```
ServicePointManager
    .ServerCertificateValidationCallback += 
    (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;
```

Answer (score -1):

Add this before execute the request;

`ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;`

it solved my problem

Comment: I think this answer requires an explanation of why this 'fixes' problem only by hiding it, and how it is not a solution that should be used for any production product :)